# Azure DevOps PHP build requiring ext-sqlsrv

Tags: php, azure-devops

I'm trying to put together a build pipeline for a PHP project I have hosted on Azure DevOps. Long story short, I need the sqlsrv PHP extension installed for my build to work. How can I configure my azure-pipelines.yml script to include that?

Here is my current script:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.3

steps:
- script: |
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
    php -version
  displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'

- script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
  displayName: 'composer install'
```

This is the error that I get in my build logs:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested PHP extension ext-sqlsrv * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sqlsrv extension.

##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
```

Comment: Is pecl installed in the image?

Comment: It wasnt. I updated my script, but now it seems that the issue is that I cannot modify the php.ini to enable the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merlin Liang's answer was a great inspiration for me, but I still struggled to get the SQLSRV accepted in composer.

First of all I had to modify some paths like David Legatt mentions.
Second problem was that I was trying to modify and restart FPM.
Key was to remove the restart part and modify CLI, not FPM.

Try this, works for me:

```
- script: sudo apt-get update
  displayName: 'Update apt package tool'

- script: |
    curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo bash -c "curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list"
    sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
    sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev    
  displayName: 'SqlSrv prerequisites install'

- script: |
    sudo apt-get -y install gcc g++ make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
    sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev
    sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
  displayName: 'PECL install'

- script: |
    sudo pecl install sqlsrv
    sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv    
  displayName: 'SqlSrv extension install'

- script: |
    sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini"
    sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"    
  displayName: 'SQLSRV modify ini files'
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure my azure-pipelines.yml script to include that?

As atymic said, you need installed `PHP Extension Community Library(pecl)` with `PEAR` first. Please try with run below script before `Use PHP version $(phpVersion)` task:

```
- script: |
    curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo bash -c "curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list"
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
    sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev

- script: |
    sudo apt-get -y install gcc g++ make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
    sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev
    sudo pecl install sqlsrv
    sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv


- script: |
    sudo bash -c "echo extension=sqlsrv.so > /etc/php7.X-sp/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini"
    sudo bash -c "echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so > /etc/php7.X-sp/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"
    sudo service php7.X-fpm-sp restart
```

The first script is used to install prerequisites for `sqlsrv` installed. The second one is for extension installed. And then, Once installed, running the third script task to create the configuration files for this extension, and restart your PHP.

Comment: The first two steps seemed to work fine. I had to fix some path issues with the first two commands in the third part because /etc/php7.3-sp/conf.d did not exist, but the php restart kept failing. I instead opted to make a build environment for my app where I configured the ORM to use sqlite instead of sqlsrv since I wasnt doing anything sqlsrv specific

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a running yaml file to execute php unit test with sqlsrv extension. It was important to choose phpVersion 7.4. Cause the latest sqlsrv module is compiled with a newer php api than the php 7.3.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  variables:
    phpVersion: '7.4'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - script: |
        sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
        php -version
      workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
      displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'

    - script: php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
      workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
      displayName: 'Get Ini location'

    - script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
      workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
      displayName: 'Composer install'

    - script: sudo apt-get update
      displayName: 'Update apt package tool'

    - script: |
        curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
        sudo bash -c "curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list"
        sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
        sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev    
      displayName: 'SqlSrv prerequisites install'

    - script: |
        sudo apt-get -y install gcc g++ make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
        sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev
        sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
      displayName: 'PECL install'

    - script: |
        sudo pecl install sqlsrv
        sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv    
      displayName: 'SqlSrv extension install'

    - script: |
        sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sqlsrv.ini"
        sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sqlsrv.ini"    
      displayName: 'SQLSRV modify ini files'

    - script: vendor/bin/phpunit
      workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
      displayName: 'Run PHP tests with phpunit'
```